# How to adjust volume settings

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any code to adjust the volume in windowsphone application. I had sound settings to stop or play and additionally i need volume adjustment in the settings. Please any one knows, how to get it.

Comment: How are you playing the audio: using XNA's MediaPlayer or Silverlight's MediaElement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use XNA API to control the volume. Here is a tutorial on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195052%28v=xnagamestudio.30%29.aspx

I think there's no way of doing this without using the XNA framework.

Comment: You could change volume on MediaElement if you're using Silverlight - it depends how the audio is being played.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I can change volumne using BackgroundAudioPlayer, so what is the best way ?

Comment: Try this from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer.volume(v=vs.92).aspx. Be aware that this is a local volume control just specific to your BackgroundAudioPlayer.